# Using Google Talk with a non-apps, non-gmail Google account

Tags: google-talk, jabber, xmpp, google-accounts

I created a Google account with an existing e-mail address from a domain that is **NOT** hosted by Google.  This address is not on an Apps domain and has no gmail service of any kind.  Still I am able to add it as a Google account on an Android device with no problem.  If the device is running Jelly Bean (where the Google Talk app allows switching between accounts) I can sign in and chat works fine.  I can also sign into Talk with this account via the [<strike>iGoogle home page</strike>](http://www.google.com/ig) (edit: [iGoogle will be discontinued](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2664197)).

Now how can I use this account with a standalone chat client like iChat, Pidgin, or Empathy?  It doesn't seem to work with login ID `user@example.com` using SSL to connect to server `talk.google.com` (tried ports 5222 and 5223).  Are iGoogle and Android doing something magical that no other Jabber client is allowed, or am I just missing a step?

Comment: I have the same problem. Also own domain, no gapps, no gmail, pidgin, all settings right (googled and tried everything I found) and "Not Authorized" as result. Very interested in solution.

Answer (score 2):

To use Google Talk with a third-party email address--despite the abilities of Android and iGoogle--it seems you really must add Gmail to your account.  If you visit gmail.com while logged in to your non-gmail Google account, you'll be presented with a form to sign up:

> #### Welcome to Gmail
>
> You're currently signed in to your user@example.edu Google Account.  If
> you complete this form, you'll be adding Gmail to this account, and
> your Gmail address will become your primary account username.

The "primary account username" part is what had been scaring me off, but it turns out:

- You can still sign in to various Google properties with your original `user@example.edu` address
- You can still hand out your real email as your Google Talk address.
- Your buddy list will remain intact, and people who you chatted with prior to adding gmail will still see you in their list.

**CAUTION:** *Choose your "throwaway" carefully; it will forever become a part of your Google account (even if you remove it "permanently"), and it is likely to be seen by your Google Talk contacts even if they add you via your original/real address.*  For this reason you should consider choosing something along the lines of `user.domain@gmail.com` as your new address

After completing the form and confirming the account, your [Google Account settings](https://www.google.com/settings/) will show your new Gmail as Primary, and list your original email address as secondary.  Now you can configure your previously un-cooperative chat client with your new @gmail login (if it doesn't work at first, you might need to sign in to Gmail proper at least once).

#### At this point, you can actually remove Gmail from your account

To do so, visit https://accounts.google.com/b/0/EditServices and select "Remove Gmail permanently".  Once you complete the process, your account will show your original email again as Primary, and list your gmail as an "Additional login".  Mail sent to this address will now bounce, but you can continue to use it as a Google Talk login.

#### Downside

Whether or not you remove Gmail after adding it, you'll still show up in buddy lists with your new @gmail address.  As cautioned above, "Remove Gmail permanently" isn't completely true!

While this may not be the perfect solution, it accomplishes the goal of being able to hand out your real email as your Google Talk address with grumpy client software even when your domain isn't on Apps.  In the end I opted to keep the gmail address on my account; I actually appreciate the side effect of having a searchable archive of my chats (a feature that can be disabled in Gmail settings).

Answer (score 1):

As far as Pidgin for an account such as abc@xyz.com

Add Account,
In the Basic Tab,
Try - Protocol = XMPP

User name = abc

Domain = xyz.com

Next head over to Advanced Tab,
Connection Securuty - Require encryption

Allow Plaintext auth over unencrypted streams - Not Required to Check this..

Connect Port - 5222

Connect server - talk.google.com

It should work, and if you are using a differnt IM, the options above should be relatively the same to key in /configure

Try it out and let know if its working..

Comment: I double-checked the password but Pidgin still reports "Not Authorized" when using these settings. I'm starting to think a throwaway gmail account is the only solution here.

Comment: Isn't working for me either.

Comment: This worked for me, looked all over for a solution, thank you!